# Setting View's visibility when RadioButton is checked

Tags: java, android

So in my app the first thing that user has to do is to chech some Radio Buttons that he wants. There are 2 Radio Groups and in each Group only one Button can be selected, so in my code I have to use nested if statements to check which RadioButtons are checked.

I'm doing it like this:

```
 if (rbMetric.isChecked()){
            if (rbSpolM.isChecked()){
      }
  }
```

And inside that second if statement i have to display some views which are previosly set to View.GONE. I do it like this:

```
etGodine.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

So the full code would look like this:

```
if (rbMetric.isChecked()){
            if (rbSpolM.isChecked()){

            etGodine.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
  }
```

But, when I check those 2 RadioButtons absolutely nothing happens! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if(checkedId==R.id.rb1){
                //then
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `rbMetric.isSelected()`  instead of `isChecked`.